# Move off/Head off/Leave

Tags: idiomatic-language, writing, verb-usage

Tom is at a party, hanging at the bar. A guy he knows, Matt, comes up to him to say hi. They talk, then -

Matt: *Well, it's good to see you again. Enjoy the party.*

Tom: *Thank you.*

Matt moves off/heads off/leaves.

Matt doesn't leave the party just Tom. Which of "moves off", "heads off" and "leaves" should I use? Or maybe all of them would be okay?

Comment: _Matt heads off to the other side/corner/opposite booth._ The most suitable here will be "heads off", but it should include a direction to where the person is heading off to. However, the use of both "leaves" and "heads off" is common as well in such situations. _Matt left John with his drink and headed off to meet his gang._

Answer (score 1):

None of them really sound right to me, in the context you mean:

- "Matt moves off": sounds strange, would make more sense if he was on something (like a bed) and moved off it.
- "Matt heads off": sounds like he is leaving the party (which you said he isn't), or if a clear goal is given ("Matt heads off in search of more interesting company")
- "Matt leaves": without more context, it sounds like he is leaving the party.

In your context (Matt is just going to talk to someone else now), I'd say something more like:

- Matt wanders off
- Matt steps away
- Matt walks off

Answer (score 0):

All are fine.  I'd probably choose "moves off".  This suggests he moves away from Tom. Probably to start another conversation with other people.  It isn't in a particular direction.

I'd use "leaves" to mean "he leaves the party"

I'd use "head off" to mean go in a particular direction, for example "Matt heads off to the toilets"